# Using site_id or site_name Inside Master Config Environment Files

Tags: multi-site-manager, focus-lab-master-config, configuration-variables

I'm engaged in the Herculean task of configuring Focus Lab Master Config with an MSM site. I'm trying to write some conditionals based on the `site_id` variable, but I keep getting errors.

Right now I'm just running this on my local server, so inside `config/config.local.php`, at the bottom, I put:

```
if ($config['site_id'] == '1') {
    $env_config['webmaster_email'] = 'me@site-one.com';
} else {
    $env_config['webmaster_email'] = 'me@site-two.com';
}
```

But when I do this it causes the page to crash (`Error 330 (net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED): Unknown error.`). The problem seems to be the `site_id` variable, because if I do something like:

```
if (1 == 1) {
    $env_config['webmaster_email'] = 'me@site-one.com';
} else {
    $env_config['webmaster_email'] = 'me@site-two.com';
}
```

Then everything is fine. I tried using `$site_id` instead of `$config['site_id']`, and I tried `site_name` instead of `site_id` but it's still not responding.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A tricky one indeed. First of all have you defined paths in each sites' index.php file as detailed in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/akuzemchak/d27570a3e52bdf656f54)?

Comment: Hi Ian - I'm actually trying to do things a bit differently, hence the conditional, so I haven't mimicked that Gist.

Comment: Config hasn't actually bootstrapped itself all the way at the point where you're trying to access it; the site_id variable might not be there yet. Let me do a couple experiments.

Answer (score 2):

Due to the order in which EE determines and sets the `site_id` config item, I would recommend that any conditions that must be on the `site_id` value be avoided and you simply have those values saved to EE's database. In this case that would mean changing the Webmaster Email value in the Control Panel.

That said, most environment conditions are in place to override what's in production. Production is "king" in most scenarios so having the `webmaster_email` value in the database without a config override is perfectly acceptable. Then in your staging, dev or local environments you can override the value with something else.

I can't think of a case where a `webmaster_email` override would be different by `site_id`. Is it possible you could take this approach?

Comment: `webmaster_email` is purely for experimental purposes to see if the conditional even *works*. I'm trying to figure out how to set more important config variables like `site_url` and `themes_path` based on which site is currently being accessed. Unfortunately I'm starting to see that if you're on Site A editing Site B, there's really no way to tell Master Config which site is currently being accessed. I think this might be a dead end :/

Comment: Yea the control panel is the tricky part because of how EE uses cookies to decide which site its using. You can check for a cookie for the `site_id` but you also need to know the cookie prefix for that.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. You know more PHP than I, why doesn't this work? `$_COOKIE[$cookie_prefix . '_cp_last_site_id']`

Comment: Is that in your config file?

Comment: No, it's in `config.local.php`. If I put `$_COOKIE['exp_cp_last_site_id']` it works, so I guess my syntax is wrong?